# Magento 2.3 Error When Accessing Products From Admin Panel

Tags: magento2.3, products-management, timeout

Receiving the following error when trying to access/edit Products through the admin panel using Magento 2.3.3:

> [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #fulltext

The page times out and does not display products - only a blank grid. This has occurred after an Akeneo import. There are no errors in the Apache log or Magento system log. Please see attached image for the full error.

[image: non-unique id error]

Comment: its warning do you get any console errors as well ?

Comment: @YasirLatif Yes, that is the console error.

Comment: errors are in a red highlighted color

Comment: @YasirLatif It appears that there are no errors. Just the warning. However, the page does not render.

Comment: did you try log out and log in again afer import this unqiueid is not related to this issue it is for search field in grid and another is for sort

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @YasirLatif Yes I did.